# NCAA Pool - Generate random teams for a list of players

Tags: python, random

Anyways, I am running a pool where 64 entrants will receive a random team from a field of 64 teams.  I'd like for it to be randomized to a decent extent, and although I understand the limitations of RNGs, I think this should be good enough.  See my code below - are there any issues with this?  Could this be done in an easier way?  Or alternatively, is this better asked in Cross Validated?

```
import random

regions = ["East", "West", "Midwest", "South"]
playerlist = []
teamlist = []

# this will be an actual list of player names when completed 
for i in range(0, 64):
    playerlist.append("Player " + str(i))

for i in range(0, 7):
    random.shuffle(playerlist)

for i in range(0, 4):
    for j in range(1, 17):
        teamlist.append(playerlist[i*16+j-1] + ": " + regions[i] + " " + str(j))

#  edited: this is unnecessary
#for i in range(0, 7):
#    random.shuffle(teamlist)

print(teamlist)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Randomly shuffling a list seven times is not any better than doing it once. So `random.shuffle(playerlist)` is enough.

In Python you almost never want to iterate over the indices of a list, rather iterate over the list itself. Here you could do:

```
import random
import itertools

regions = "East", "West", "Midwest", "South"
players = ["Player {}".format(i) for i in range(64)]
teams = range(1, len(players) / len(regions) + 1)
random.shuffle(players)

teamlist = ["{}: {} {}".format(player, *team) for player, team in 
            zip(players, itertools.product(regions, teams))]

print(teamlist)
```

Here I used [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to make formatting the different strings easier and [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to construct a list (actually an iterable) of `region, team`:

```
>>> list(itertools.product(regions, teams))
[('East', 1), ('East', 2), ('East', 3), ('East', 4), ('East', 5), ('East', 6), ('East', 7), ('East', 8), ('East', 9), ('East', 10), ('East', 11), ('East', 12), ('East', 13), ('East', 14), ('East', 15), ('East', 16), ('West', 1), ('West', 2), ('West', 3), ('West', 4), ('West', 5), ('West', 6), ('West', 7), ('West', 8), ('West', 9), ('West', 10), ('West', 11), ('West', 12), ('West', 13), ('West', 14), ('West', 15), ('West', 16), ('Midwest', 1), ('Midwest', 2), ('Midwest', 3), ('Midwest', 4), ('Midwest', 5), ('Midwest', 6), ('Midwest', 7), ('Midwest', 8), ('Midwest', 9), ('Midwest', 10), ('Midwest', 11), ('Midwest', 12), ('Midwest', 13), ('Midwest', 14), ('Midwest', 15), ('Midwest', 16), ('South', 1), ('South', 2), ('South', 3), ('South', 4), ('South', 5), ('South', 6), ('South', 7), ('South', 8), ('South', 9), ('South', 10), ('South', 11), ('South', 12), ('South', 13), ('South', 14), ('South', 15), ('South', 16)]
```

Note that `0` is the default start argument for a `range`.

If your script becomes longer, you should probably add a [`if __name__ == "__main__":`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard to allow importing your code from other scripts.